# How to switch to another activity after the last element in an array is displayed?

Tags: java, android, arrays

Im new in programming and im having difficulties with my program..I want to switch from main activity to result activity after the last element in array is displayed but seems like my if else statement is wrong..ive tried other references but its not working..Help please..

```
private int currentQuestion;
private String [] questions;
private String [] answers;
private Button answerButton;
private Button questionButton;
private TextView questionView;
private TextView answerView;
private EditText answerText;


int score=0;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
}

public void init()
{
    questions = new String[]{"What is my dog name?", "Who is my Crush?"};
    answers = new String[]{"Butchick","Michael"};

    currentQuestion = -1;


    answerButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    questionButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    questionView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    answerView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    answerText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    answerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer();  
        }});

    questionButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {




            if(currentQuestion<2){


                currentQuestion++;

                if(currentQuestion==questions.length)
                    currentQuestion=0;

                questionView.setText(questions[currentQuestion]);
                answerView.setText("");
                answerText.setText("");

                return;



                }else{

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();


                }




        }});

}





public boolean isCorrect(String answer){
    return(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[currentQuestion]));


}


public void checkAnswer(){

    String answer = answerText.getText().toString();

    if(isCorrect(answer)){

        answerView.setText("Youre Right!!");

        score++;

    }


    else {
        answerView.setText("Sorry, the correct answer is  "+answers[currentQuestion]);

    }



}
```

}

Comment: Proper indenting and less whitespace would help a lot in readability.

Comment: Pro tip: try indenting your code a little bit better

Answer (score 0):

Check this part on your code.

```
if(currentQuestion==questions.length)
                currentQuestion=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove below code

```
if(currentQuestion==questions.length)
                currentQuestion=0;
```

Thats it...

Comment: ok fine here more changes move currentQuestion++; to above  if(currentQuestion<2) condition..